# Pre-1990 anime movie with an alien princess, scientist father who crashes into Earth and ending with a nuke

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I've been trying to find this movie that I must have watched a hundred times growing up. I watched a dubbed version and it was probably pre-1990.

There were standard tropes - alien princess, scientist father crashing ship into Earth, combiner robot made up of 3 ships. The scientist was the father of the princess; I believe her hair was green? The ending was the hero carrying the dead princess towards the camera in the aftermath of a nuke.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)